# Login using Json

Tags: javascript, json, web-services

I am trying to develop a login process using json.
My problem is that when I make many login attempts ,  parameters are not overriden but concatenated.
Below is the code I'm writing.
I do not see where the problem is.
Thank you in advance .

```
var loginReq = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

    loginReq.onload = function() {


var json = this.responseText;
Titanium.API.info("step 1 done");
var response = JSON.parse(json);

if (response.status == true) {


    Titanium.App.Properties.setString("key", response.key);
    alert("Success");

} else {
    alert("Email or password wrong");
}
};



 function doConnVerif() {

if ($.email.value != '' && $.password.value != '') {

    loginReq.open("POST", "URL");

    loginReq.send({
        'email' : $.email.value ,
        'password' : $.password.value

    });



} else {
    alert("Enter email and password");

}
  }
```

Comment: Your post is missing some code

Comment: what is the missing part ??

Answer (score 0):

By your question I can't grasp the full aspect of the problem, but definitely a good idea would be only allow one login attempt at a time.

Something like:

```
var pendingRequest = false;

// ...

if(!pendingRequest) {
    loginReq.send({
        'email' : $.email.value ,
        'password' : $.password.value
    });
    pendingRequest = true
}

// ...
loginReq.onload = function() {
    pendingRequest = false
// ...
```

Comment: The problem is not  many login attempts in the same time .  The problem si that when i make a good attempt for the first time i recieve a good result , but after that  when i  make other  attempts with good password and email i always recieve " Email or password wrong" !!

Comment: Can you describe those steps? You make a login attempt and it works, then you enter your app. After that you logout and when you login again you receive the error, is that it?

Comment: Yes it's exactly that . After logout i always recieve the error  !

Comment: i don't implement a logout code  . this is just an error message who appear when thera are a wrong email or password .